# Using an integer on a for each loop in xslt

Tags: xslt, foreach

I am trying to use XSLT to generate a dynamic class based on the number of groups it finds in the XML. For example there will be X groups in the XML, all with child nodes. I need the for each loop to dynamically create a class name based on which group number it is in the list. I can populate the group name without a problem, but I can't find any clear information of how to append the system generated part to the class.
For example:

- groupblue class = "groupblue-1"
- grouporange class = "grouporange-2"
- groupred class = "groupred-3"

Etc etc, for every group in the XML.

I hope this makes sense and someone is able to help! Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

XML

```
<group>
  <title>Title Content</title>
  <text>Content 1</text>
</group>
<group>
  <title>Title Content</title>
  <text>Content 2</text>
</group>
<group>
  <title>Title Content</title>
  <text>Content 3</text>
</group>
```

HTML output

```
<div id="titlecontent-1">
  text from group 1 content
</div>
<div id="titlecontent-2">
  text from group 2 content
</div>
<div id="titlecontent-3">
  text from group 3 content
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post some example XML and desired output? It will make it easier to see what the criteria are for grouping and suggest solution(s) for how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="group">
     <div id="{translate(title, ' ', '')}-{position()}">
       <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
     </div>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this well-formed XML document** (that wraps the provided XML fragment into a top element):

```
<t>
    <group>
        <title>Title Content</title>
        <text>Content 1</text>
    </group>
    <group>
        <title>Title Content</title>
        <text>Content 2</text>
    </group>
    <group>
        <title>Title Content</title>
        <text>Content 3</text>
    </group>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<div id="TitleContent-1">Content 1</div>
<div id="TitleContent-2">Content 2</div>
<div id="TitleContent-3">Content 3</div>
```